# Ionic 3 - How to throw custom error Objects

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm struggling with a question. If you guys could please help me with it. Thanks in advance. I would like to throw custom error objects from my Services components.

**Edit**: Why do I want to create custom error classes?
I have a website that has been built with Angular 5, and I'm going to build a mobile app using Ionic3+Angular5. I would like to build 2 separate 'Front-end' projects and share my services between those two projects. The back-end API returns a custom error JSON, as shown below:

```
"error": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "messages": ["Custom message from the back-end API"]
}
```

My custom error classes will encapsulate these errors, and I'm going to share those custom error objects between the two apps. At end each app would manage/handle differently those errors. (I'm not sure if it is a good approach, I'm just testing it). **End Edit**.

I've build the following code:

Ionic version:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

I created a blank Ionic project:

```
$ ionic start testIonic blank --type=ionic-angular
```

Then I created three objects to encapsulate custom errors:

```
export class MyAppError{

    private statusCode : number;
    private defaultMessage: string;
    private customMessages: string[];

    constructor(private originalError: Response) {
        // logic to get/extract the Custom Error JSON
    }

    getOriginalError() : Response {   return this.originalError;     }
    gettatusCode() : number {         return this.statusCode;    }
    getDefaultMessage() : string {    return this.defaultMessage;   }
    getCustomMessages() : string[] {  return this.customMessages;    }
}

export class MyAppNotFoundError extends MyAppError {
}

export class MyAppConnectionError extends MyAppError {
}
```

My service class gets a list of countries from an API (getAllCountries function). The handleError function throws custom error objects:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Country } from '../_model/country';
import { MyAppError } from '../_error_handlers/myapp-error';
import { MyAppConnectionError } from '../_error_handlers/myapp-connection-error';
import { MyAppNotFoundError } from '../_error_handlers/myapp-notfound-error';

@Injectable()
export class CountryService {

  public BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/v1/country';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllCountries(): Observable<Country[]>{
    return this.http.get<Country[]>( this.BASE_URL + "/get-all" )
      .catch( this.handleError );
  }

  protected handleError(error: Response) : Observable<any> {
    if (!error.status || error.status === 0){
      return Observable.throw( new MyAppConnectionError(error) );
    }
    if (error.status === 404){
      return  Observable.throw( new MyAppNotFoundError(error) );
    }
    return  Observable.throw( new MyAppError(error) );
  }
}
```

The country class:

```
export class Country{
    countryId:  string;
    description: string;
}
```

I have added CountryService into app.module.ts:

```
  providers: [ 
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    CountryService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

I've also added HttpClientModule into app.module.ts:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
```

I call the service from home.ts:

```
  getAllCountries(){
    this.countryService.getAllCountries()
      .subscribe(
        (list)=>{
          this.countries = list;
        },
        (error : MyAppError) => {
          console.log("Debug1: " + error );
          console.log("Debug2: " + (error instanceof MyAppError) );
          console.log("Debug3: " + (error instanceof MyAppNotFoundError) );
          console.log("Debug4: " + (error instanceof MyAppConnectionError) );
        }
      );
  } // end method
```

I put a simple button on my home.html to call that function:

```
<button ion-button (click)="getAllCountries()">Button</button>
```

The main ideia is:

- when my API url is down, or when I am not connected to the internet, then error.status === 0. It returns Observable.throw( new MyAppConnectionError(error) ).
- when I test this code using an wrong URL, then error.status === 404. It returns Observable.throw( new MyAppNotFoundError(error) ).

However, when I click the button, my function in home.ts prints to the browser console:

```
Debug1: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.throw is not a function
home.ts:28 Debug2: false
home.ts:29 Debug3: false
home.ts:30 Debug4: false
```

I am not getting an MyAppError or MyAppNotFoundError or MyAppConnectionError object instance, even though they have been thrown from my service.
Could you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you very much.
(English isn't my first language, please excuse any mistake).

Comment: Out of curiosity what is so unique about your app that you need to use this approach?

Comment: Hello @Sergey. I have two apps: a website that has been built using Angular 5, and a mobile version that will be build in Ionic3+Angular5.
I would like to build 2 separate 'Front-end' projects and share my services between those two projects.
I thought it would be a good approach if I encapsulate errors in custom error objects, and also share those custom error classes between the two apps.
At end each app would manage/handle differently those errors.
Do you think it is a good approach? Please feel free to suggest me a different approach. I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I see, I have similar case: I have progressive web-app and ionic apps (hybrids) all of them share a service (API). I follow the approach from here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling on both type of clients but on every client the logic of how errors are handled is slightly different. I am still not clear why to achieve what you want you need to create custom error objects (I might be also missing something;)

Comment: @Sergey, thank you for answering me, and also for sharing that tutorial link. It is very useful and interesting, I've been reading it. I will test a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following "import" in the CountryService class:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

It works now. I am able to get an MyAppError object instance.